# Object doesn't support this property or method 'exec'

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using `JQuery 1.11.2.min.js` for `IE8`. I use Bootstrap 3 and Jasny bootstrap and form validation plugins also.

Now, after I add `respond.js` and `html5shive.js` all errors are resolved except this error in `JQuery.1.11.2min.js` **line 5053**:

> Object doesn't support this property or method 'exec'

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

somebody already had the same problem, you have to alter the jquery library code to make it work

[jQuery on IE8, error: Object doesn't support this property or method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987842/jquery-on-ie8-error-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method)