# Extending Object is breaking my code. What can I do?

Tags: javascript

So I wrote a helper function

```
Object.prototype.Where = function ( boofunc ) {
  // Returns an object whose own properties are  
  // those properties p of this object that satisify
  // the condition boofunc(p)

    var that = new Object();
    for ( var prop in this )
    {
        if ( this.hasOwnProperty(prop) && boofunc(this[prop]) )
        that[prop] = this[prop];
    }
    return that;
}
```

which I've determined is wrecking my code as it's giving me errors such as

> Object doesn't support property or method 'exec'

in other JavaScript files that I've included. The problem is that I've already used this function like 100 times ... so I'm wondering whether there is any way that I can change the body that will fix what the problem is. If I have to get rid of this function and change it to something like

```
function Where ( obj, boofunc ) 
{
        var newobj = new Object();
        for ( var prop in obj )
        {
            if ( obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && boofunc(obj[prop]) )
            newobj[prop] = obj[prop];
        }
        return newobj;
}
```

then I have to go through 100 different places in my code to change it.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987842/jquery-on-ie8-error-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method

Answer (score 0):

I would change it in your code, using regex and find and replace you could get most of it done fairly easily. This is why you shouldn't modify native objects especially Object which all else inherits functionality from, It means that String.where() Function.where() etc.. might be breaking your code.

also if you must modify a native prototype you should first check to see that that method or property has not been added.

```
if( typeof Object.prototype.where === 'undefined' ){
  Object.prototype.where = function where(){ ... }
}
```